# OpenGL + QT: render to texture and display it back

Tags: qt, opengl, fbo, glreadpixels

After some trouble I've managed to correctly render to texture inside a Frame Buffer Object in a Qt 4.8 application: I can open an OpenGL context with a QGLWidget, render to a FBO, and use this one as a texture.

Now I need to display the texture rendered in a QPixmap and show it in some other widget in the gui. But.. nothing is shown.

Those are some pieces of code:

```
// generate texture, FBO, RBO in the initializeGL
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboId);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

// now in paintGL
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
// .... render into texture code ....
if(showTextureInWidget==false) {
    showTextureInWidget = true;
    char *pixels;
    pixels = new  char[TEXTURE_WIDTH * TEXTURE_HEIGHT * 4];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    QPixmap qp = QPixmap(pixels);
    QLabel *l = new QLabel();
    // /* TEST */ l->setText(QString::fromStdString("dudee"));
    l->setPixmap(qp);
    QWidget *d = new QWidget;
    l->setParent(d);
    d->show();
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // unbind
// now draw the scene with the rendered texture
```

I see the Widget opened but.. there is nothing inside it. If I decomment the test line.. I see the "dudee" string so I know that there is a qlabel but.. no image from the QPixmap.

I know that the original data are ´unsigned char´ and I'm using ´char´ and I've tried with some different color parameters (´GL_RGBA´, ´GL_RGB´ etc) but I don't think this is the point.. the point is that I don't see anything..

Any advice? If I have to post more code I will do it!

#### Edit:

I haven't posted all the code, but the fact I'd like to be clear is that the texture is correctly rendered as a texture inside a cube. I'm just not able to put it back in the cpu from gpu

#### Edit 2:

Thanks to the peppe answer I found out the problem: I needed a Qt object that accept as a constructor some raw pixels data. Here is the complete snippet:

```
    uchar *pixels;
    pixels = new uchar[TEXTURE_WIDTH * TEXTURE_HEIGHT * 4];
    for(int i=0; i < (TEXTURE_WIDTH * TEXTURE_HEIGHT * 4) ; i++ ) {
        pixels[i] = 0;
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
    glReadPixels( 0,0,  TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    qi = QImage(pixels, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    qi = qi.rgbSwapped();

    QLabel *l = new QLabel();
    l->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qi));
    QWidget *d = new QWidget;
    l->setParent(d);
    d->show();
```

Comment: Your code seems clearly incomplete -- for instance you're not setting up any color attachment for your FBO. Also, when using FBOs, *do always* check their completeness status by using `glCheckFramebufferStatus` -- anything bug `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` tells you that your FBO is not usable.

Comment: yeah it is in the code, i just haven't copied it. of course I'm doing the checks with `glCheckFramebufferStatus`. The fact I'd like to be clear is that the rendered texture (as a texture of a cube) is correctly rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that that's not all of your code and -- as you say -- the texture is correctly filled, then there's a little mistake going on here:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
QPixmap qp = QPixmap(pixels);
```

The `QPixmap(const char *)` ctor wants a XPM image, not raw pixels. You need to use one of the QImage ctors to create a valid QImage. (You can also pass ownership to the QImage, solving the fact that you're currently leaking `pixels`...)

Once you do that, you'll figure out that

1. the image is flipped vertically, as OpenGL has the origin in the bottom left corner, growing upwards/rightwards, while Qt assumes origin in the top left, growing to downwards/rightwards;
2. the channels might be swapped -- i.e. OpenGL is returning data with the wrong endianess. I don't remember in this case if using `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SWAP_BYTES)` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` as the type may help, eventually you need to resort to a CPU-side loop to fix your pixel data :)